# SSRS: DataSource gets overwritten, of a SubReport in a Grid has the same one

Tags: c#, reporting-services

The title might be a bit confusing, so I try to explain the problem: I'd like to pass Data to a SubReport, which is calculated in the code behind. So I created a DataSource, putted the SubReport in a Grid and set the DataContext to the Grid. This makes sure the SubReport gets called after the Data is calculated.
Everything fine so far.
But now the interesting part: The SubReport has another DataSource, which has the same name as a DataSource in the Mainreport. This DataSource in the Mainreport gets now overwritten by the DataSource in the SubReport. Interesting enought, this happens ONLY IF THE SUBREPORT IS IN A GRID, otherwise it doesn't.

Is there any explenation for this behaviour?